# Algeciras to Ceuta/Tanger on budget?

Tags: public-transport, budget, transportation, spain, morocco

I'd like to have one-day trip Algeciras-Ceuta (or, at least/alternatively, Tarifa/Tanger, either of 4 mentioned). Checked ferries and the price (60 EUR) seems unreasonable, planes all over Europe are cheaper.

Is there any way to get there and back cheaper? One passenger, no vehicle.

Comment: @pnuts depends on what 'slightly' means. I can afford ~$20 round trip.